Cascading rolling total logic in SQL
I am trying to recreate the cascading sum logic of our Student Information System (SIS) to build a tracking report that will aggregate all graduation requirements in one place.
Currently courses can have between 1 and 5 subjects associated with them, each subject has a cap or minimum requirement to be met, and if that total is met then credit that would feed into that subject would cascade to subject2, subject 3, etc. Then finally into Electives if all subject "buckets" are full.
Is this possible with SQL, as I would prefer to run this at the SQL level?
I had tried setting up a recursive CTE to calculate this but a solution has eluded me. Any help or suggestions would be very appreciated.
Example Tables:
credit req table



subject
maxCredit




ART
1.0


CAREER & TECH
1.0


CIVICS
0.5


CONT WRLD PROB
0.5


ENGLISH
4.0


HEALTH
0.5


MATHEMATICS
3.0


PHYSICAL ED
1.5


SCIENCE
1.0


U.S. HISTORY
1.0


ELECTIVE
7.0



student course history sample
CREATE TABLE StudentCourses (
    stuID INT,
    crsID VARCHAR(10),
    crsTitle VARCHAR(50),
    creditEarned DECIMAL(3,3),
    subject1 VARCHAR(50),
    subject2 VARCHAR(50),
    subject3 VARCHAR(50),
    subject4 VARCHAR(50),
    subject5 VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO StudentCourses (stuID, crsID, crsTitle, creditEarned, subject1, subject2, subject3, subject4, subject5)
VALUES
(12345, 'TRMSC', 'SPANISH I', 0.500, 'MISCELLANEOUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '7732', 'CHEMISTRY', 0.500, 'SCIENCE', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '2371', 'AP ENG LIT/COMP', 0.500, 'ENGLISH', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '3611', 'PAP INT MTH III', 0.500, 'MATHEMATICS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '8031', 'PAP WA ST HIST', 0.500, 'WASH ST HISTORY', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '7772', 'PHYSICS', 0.500, 'SCIENCE', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '2242', 'PAP ENGLISH 10', 0.500, 'ENGLISH', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '8242', 'AP US HISTORY', 0.500, 'U.S. HISTORY', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '0262', 'POTTERY I', 0.500, 'ART', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '2372', 'AP ENG LIT/COMP', 0.500, 'ENGLISH', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '1521', 'SPANISH 2', 0.500, 'MISCELLANEOUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '7641', 'ZOOLOGY', 0.500, 'SCIENCE', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '4281', 'BUSINESS LAW', 0.500, 'CAREER & TECH', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '1522', 'SPANISH 2', 0.500, 'MISCELLANEOUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '4291', 'AD BUSINESS LAW', 0.500, 'CAREER & TECH', 'CAREER & TECH', NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '9872', 'STUD GOVT', 0.500, 'MISCELLANEOUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '7642', 'ZOOLOGY', 0.500, 'SCIENCE', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '9871', 'STUD GOVT', 0.500, 'MISCELLANEOUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, 'TRMTH', 'ALGEBRA', 1.000, 'MATHEMATICS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '2171', 'PAP ENGLISH 9', 0.500, 'ENGLISH', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '3821', 'AP CALCULUS', 0.500, 'MATHEMATICS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '4201', 'TECH TOOL FYF', 0.500, 'CAREER & TECH', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '0261', 'POTTERY I', 0.500, 'ART', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '6252V', 'HEALTH WELLNESS', 0.500, 'HEALTH', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '9603H', 'HSPE SCIENCE', 0.250, 'MISCELLANEOUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '6291', 'PSYCH/HLTH ISS', 0.500, 'CAREER & TECH', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '2592', 'SR COMP/CON CUL', 0.500, 'ENGLISH', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '7771', 'PHYSICS', 0.500, 'SCIENCE', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '2591', 'SR COMP/CON CUL', 0.500, 'ENGLISH', 'CAREER & TECH', NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '9871', 'STUD GOVT', 0.500, 'MISCELLANEOUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '3822', 'AP CALCULUS', 0.500, 'MATHEMATICS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '9871', 'STUD GOVT', 0.500, 'MISCELLANEOUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '7731', 'CHEMISTRY', 0.500, 'SCIENCE', 'CAREER & TECH', NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '8072', 'PAP WORLD STUDY', 0.500, 'CONT WRLD PROB', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '9872', 'STUD GOVT', 0.500, 'MISCELLANEOUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '6202', 'AEROBIC FITNESS', 0.500, 'PHYSICAL ED', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '9601H', 'HSPE READING', 0.250, 'MISCELLANEOUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '3602', 'INTEG MATH III', 0.500, 'MATHEMATICS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, 'TRMSC', 'SPANISH I', 0.500, 'MISCELLANEOUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '3831', 'CALCULUS II', 0.500, 'MATHEMATICS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '3832', 'CALCULUS II', 0.500, 'MATHEMATICS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '8441', 'AP COMP GOV/POL', 0.500, 'CIVICS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '9872', 'STUD GOVT', 0.500, 'MISCELLANEOUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '6292', 'PSYCH/HLTH ISS', 0.500, 'CAREER & TECH', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '9872', 'STUD GOVT', 0.500, 'MISCELLANEOUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '6201', 'AEROBIC FITNESS', 0.500, 'PHYSICAL ED', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '2172', 'PAP ENGLISH 9', 0.500, 'ENGLISH', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '9604H', 'HSPE WRITING', 0.250, 'MISCELLANEOUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, 'TRMTH', 'GEOMETRY', 1.000, 'MATHEMATICS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '3701', 'PAP INT MATH IV', 0.500, 'MATHEMATICS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '3702', 'PAP INT MATH IV', 0.500, 'MATHEMATICS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '8241', 'AP US HISTORY', 0.500, 'U.S. HISTORY', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '8511', 'CUL PRJ/HS BYND', 0.500, 'SENIOR PROJECT', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '9871', 'STUD GOVT', 0.500, 'MISCELLANEOUS', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(12345, '8442', 'AP COMP GOV/POL', 0.500, 'CONT WRLD PROB', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

Expected Outcome (math is not accounting for cascade)



subject
maxCredits
stuSubject
creditsEarned






MISCELLANEOUS
6.750




SENIOR PROJECT
0.500




WASH ST HISTORY
0.500


ART
1.0
ART
1.000


CAREER & TECH
1.0
CAREER & TECH
2.500


CIVICS
0.5
CIVICS
0.500


CONT WRLD PROB
0.5
CONT WRLD PROB
1.000


ENGLISH
4.0
ENGLISH
4.000


HEALTH
0.5
HEALTH
0.500


MATHEMATICS
3.0
MATHEMATICS
6.000


PHYSICAL ED
1.5
PHYSICAL ED
1.000


SCIENCE
1.0
SCIENCE
3.000


U.S. HISTORY
1.0
U.S. HISTORY
1.000




Can you provide the expected output ?

Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. See Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question, #5 and #3.

I don't get it at all, the expected output doesn't seem to have anything to do with the second paragraph in the question , the source data makes no sense to me why would a student be attending multiple courses with the same subjects. As far as I recall (and it's a long time ago ) the hierarchy is students sign up for a course, course has modules and modules have subjects.

The top table lists the minimum credit requirements for graduation. Most of our courses award .5 credit upon completion. There are two approaches I'm going for this, first and primarily to recreate the logic that our system has in place, which the vendor is reluctant to send the source code and calculations. As well as a total sum, so that counselors can see if a student took 6 English credits because they want to be an English Major in College. This second point is pretty easy.

"I had tried setting up a recursive CTE ..."  So where's that try?  We don't see it posted here.

This is a simple joining to get the final table.
Check as follows:
WITH SC AS (
    select DISTINCT
        subject1 as stuSubject,
        SUM(creditEarned) OVER (PARTITION BY subject1) AS creditEarned
    from StudentCourses
)
SELECT 
    CR.subject,
    -- CR.maxcredit,
    CASE 
       WHEN CR.maxcredit IS NOT NULL 
          THEN CAST(CR.maxcredit AS DECIMAL(2,1))
    END maxcredit,
    SC.stuSubject,
    SC.creditEarned
FROM SC left join CreditReq CR
on SC.stuSubject = CR.subject
ORDER BY  CR.subject;

demo code: db<>fiddle

